# In SphinxSearch, how to sort by multiple factors (some are not related to search)?

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, sphinx

Aside from weight, we would also like to factor certain elements into the ranking of search results (num_views, price, etc).

`$results = $sphinx->search($query, 'products')
            ->setMatchMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2)->query();`

How can I combine `weight` with other factors such as `num_view`? (Note, I don't want to order by the two fields separately, I want to be able to combine the two fields into one score.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SphinxQL you can use this:

```
SELECT id, weight() + num_view AS my_weight FROM products 
    WHERE match('some query') ORDER BY my_weight DESC
```

`weight() + num_view` is a simple example of combining two factors into one weight value.

I suppose that in Sphinx PHP API you can do the same using [SetSelect](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setselect) and [SetSortMode](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setsortmode) functions.